# OpenWeather API responds with unexpected results

Tags: android, android-fragments, location

For some reason the Api responds with different coordinates set to those i sent. I have debugged the application and the results from the call to api differ to those returned in a JSON file. For example
Those sent:

1. http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=lat=51.89689166666667&lon=-8.486315

Those returned

1. {"coord":{"lon":24.76,"lat":60.15},"weather":..................
   Here is the code I am using currently:

   private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
               "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

   ```
      URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API + "lat="+lat+"&"+"lon="+lon));
           HttpURLConnection connection =
                   (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

           connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key",
                   context.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

           StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
           String tmp="";
           while((tmp=reader.readLine())!=null)
               json.append(tmp).append("\n");
           reader.close();

           JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know anything about android or this service in particular, but I just looked up their [API](http://openweathermap.org/current#geo) since I thought your URL looked dubious, and found this:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139
```

Notice there is no `?q=` like in your example, and in your variable `private static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";`

When I remove the `q=` (and add the demo API key from their website examples), we get a working URL *that returns data for the specified lat/long*:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.89689166666667&lon=-8.486315&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98